# Spivak chapter 3 question 6 part (b)

Tags: calculus

Given x1=1, x2=2, x3=3, which means n=3 and Deg f = 2, I have found three functions :

```
1) f1(x)=1/2(x^2)-(5/2)x+3
```

```
2) f2(x)=-x^2+4x+3
```

```
3) f3(x)=1/2(x^2)-3/2x+1
```

which helped me understand part (a) of this question.

Can I have some help or an example for part (b)?
We want a function Deg f = n-1, such as f(xi)=ai, where a1, ... , an, are given numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Look at this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html